# Is possible backgroundworker DoWork in main thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, unity-game-engine, backgroundworker

Is possible backgroundworker DoWork in main thread?
I meant if some device only have one CPU , Is it possible to happen?

PS: I'm working on unity , So run Android & IOS & Windows Platform.

```
    System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker bw = new System.ComponentModel.BackgroundWorker();
    bool inMainThread = false;
    int mainThreadId = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;

    bw.DoWork += (object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e) =>
        {   // Is it possible equal true ??
            inMainThread = mainThreadId == System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        }
```

Comment: "I meant if some device only have one CPU , Is it possible to happen?" There's a big difference between a *CPU* and a *thread*. There are generally *far* more threads in a system than there are CPUs.

Comment: *"I meant if some device only have one CPU , Is it possible to happen"* if this were true, windows wouldn't work. it would be busy running one application (itself) and die

Comment: If it's on the main thread, it's not in the background, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not possible. A `BackgroundWorker` will always do its work on an seperate thread.

To the point with an system with only one CPU. An OS runs many programs asynchronous and every program can have many threads. The OS will schedule all this threads to run at somepoint on any available CPU. This is crucial to maintain a smooth running system, especially when a system has only one CPU.

If you want to know more you could look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheduling_(computing)) or [here](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~cs161/notes/scheduling.pdf) and for a start I would recommend [this](https://youtu.be/7ENFeb-J75k) video.